# Page not found error in Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm really new to node.js . and i was watching a tutorial and implementing it. but there is a problem and i can't figure it out. Now, I was trying to make a new page,and i did the following changes but the server is saying page not found and there is no error on the console in any file. Can somebody help me please.

app.js

```
// bunch of other code
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var about = require('./routes/about');
app.use('/about',about);
// bunch of other code
```

routes/about.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET about page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.render('about', {
    title: "About",
    name: "Poloos"});
});

module.exports = router;
```

view/about.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><%= title %></title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
</head>
<body>
<h1><%= title %></h1>
<p>Welcome to Sheikh's NodeJS</p>
<% include templates/navigation.ejs %>
<p>So this is the about page. The name of the character is <% name %> from     Breaking Bad!!!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What URL are you requesting from your browser?

Comment: `app.user('/about',about);`, did you mean to use `app.use`

Comment: @PatrickEvans..yeah sorry.. i made this mistake while writing the question here,, sorry. let me fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys. i just found out what was wrong with this code. Turns out the code is fine, i just restarted my www file and boom, its working, that's pretty stupid of me though.

Comment: You can use [`nodemon`](http://nodemon.io/) or alternatives to avoid restarting your server manually.